# are all transitive reductions of a graph isomorphic?

Tags: graph-isomorphism

Transitive reduction of a graph is not unique. Take this example:

[image]

Now if we remove the labels, the two reduced graphs are isomorphic:

[image]

are all transitive reductions of a directed graph isomorphic ? (I'm interested in weakly connected digraphs by the way)